# How to add number of days defined by float variable to a Date in SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a `float` variable which describes a term in months.
I need to be able to add this period to a given date.

I created a simple logic such as:

```
DECLARE @monthsTerm  AS float = 2;
Select DATEADD(dd,((CAST(@monthsTerm AS INT) % 1) / 0.25 * 7), (DATEADD(mm, CAST(@monthsTerm AS INT), '2018-01-01')))  AS [Subscription end date]
```

The problem appears when I want to set the `monthsTerm` variable to a 1, 2 or 3 weeks, etc. period of time. So for two weeks period, the variable would look like:

```
DECLARE @monthsTerm  AS float = 0.5;
```

and I expect to get `'2018-01-15'` as a result, but now it returns '2018-01-01' which is wrong.

I thought about transferring the expression to just a:

```
Select DATEADD(dd,((@monthsTerm % 1) / 0.25 * 7), (DATEADD(mm, CAST(@monthsTerm AS INT), '2018-01-01')))  AS [Subscription end date]
```

however, I'm getting an exception:

```
The data types float and int is incompatible in the modulo operator.
```

I know that for instance the similar expression would work in C#:

```
public DateTime EndDate
=> StartDate.AddMonths((int)TermMonths).AddDays((TermMonths % 1) / 0.25 * 7);
```

Is there any simple workaround to this so I can have only one simple expression with `Select DATEADD(..` or I need to end up with some more complex solution? Cheers

Comment: Rewrite the formula to use weeks and do the translation from months to weeks before feeding it into the function?

Comment: But in a case when the `@monthsTerm = 1` I don't want to add 4weeks(28days) but the full month and each month can have different numbers of days 30, 31 or 29,28 in case of February.

Comment: Fair. I didn't think that one all the way through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select
    cast((CAST(@monthsTerm*100 as int) % 100)*7 /0.25/100 as int) as days ,                                  
    (((CAST(@monthsTerm*100 as int) % 100)/100) / 0.25 * 7),
    DATEADD(dd,cast((CAST(@monthsTerm*100 as int) % 100)*7 /0.25/100 as int), (DATEADD(mm, CAST(@monthsTerm AS INT), '2018-01-01')))  AS [Subscription end date]
```

Multiplying with `100`, and dividing by `100` after the `%`

Comment: I applied the thing to some more complex query and works just fine, thanks very much!